# Salesforce APEX: How to create and parse HL7 V2.3 messages

Tags: parsing, salesforce, apex, hl7-v2

Within our Salesforce APEX-based health cloud application we interface with a 3rd EMR supporting HL7 V2.3 over HTTP.

We are looking for an ability to create and parse HL7 v2.3 messages in APEX and then use HTTP as a transport to send/received from the 3rd party EMR.

Please point us to how this can be done!